# Friend function is not accessing private members of another friend class

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function

I have two classes Term and Polynomial. Polynomial class is declared to be a friend of Term class. Polynomial class has friend function in it. When i implement that function in a cpp file of Polynomial class, the private members of Term are not getting accessed there. Although the Polynomial class is declared to be its friend. All i need is to have access private members of Term in that function. Any help? Here is my code:

Polynomial.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Term.h"
using namespace std;

// class polynomial;
// friend operator+(const polynomial& , const polynomial&);
class Polynomial
{
private:
    Term *termArray;
    int capacity;
    int terms;

public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(int, int);
    friend Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& , const Polynomial&);
};
```

Here is my Term.h:

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;
class Polynomial;

class Term
{
friend Polynomial;

private:
    int exp;
    float coef;
};
```

Here is my Polynomial.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include "Term.h"
using namespace std;

Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    capacity = 1;
    terms = 0;
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int cap, int noOfTerms)
{
    capacity = cap;
    terms = noOfTerms;
    termArray = new Term[terms];
}

Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &a, const Polynomial &b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<a.terms; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < b.terms; j++)
            if(a.termArray[i].exp == b.termArray[j].exp)
            {
                //something to do here.
            }
}
```

The error that i am getting is at "exp" within if condition of overloaded function of + that it is inaccessible.

Comment: Your `Term` class is only usable by `Polynomial`. It might as well be a nested class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &a, const Polynomial&b)` is trying to access the private members of `Term` not `Polynomial` class.

So `Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &a, const Polynomial&b)` has to be a friend of `Term` too.

Answer (score 2):

`exp` is not accessible inside the `operator+`, because friendship is **not transitive** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class)):

> If class A is a friend of class B, and class B is a friend of class C,
>   class A is not automatically a friend of class C.

This applies to friend function too. You have to add the `friend` declaration to `Term` too or provide accessor functions.

Comment: OK, I found it on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) too, it's the first thing in notes. I thought it would be more formal, but no.

Answer (score 0):

The operator+ function isn't actually part of the Polynomial class since it's a friend function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465sdshe.aspx

See the "friend functions" section.

Answer (score 0):

Your **free function** `Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &a, const Polynomial&b)` is not a member of `Term` so it would be allowed access to the privates, nor a member of it's friend `Polynomial` (only a friend, and that's not transitive), and thus also doesn't get access to `Term`'s innards that way.

Either make it a member of `Polynomial` to take advantage of the existing friend-relationship, or preferably make it a friend of `Term` as well.
There is a sneaky third option, though you probably don't want that, which is defining it inline in `Polynomial` but keeping it a free function.